# Steering columns squeaks only when tilted upwards

Tags: nissan, steering, noise, versa

I'm driving a 2015 Nissan Versa and noticed the steering column squeaks, but only when past a certain point when tilting upwards.  Fully tilted upwards, it squeaks the most.  Halfway down, slight squeaking.  All the way down, no squeaking at all.  Turning the wheel doesn't seem to cause it, but the vibrations of the road does.

And it locks in pretty tight - I don't feel any movement of the wheel.

Does anyone know what might be causing this and how to resolve my squeaking issue?

Comment: Isn't this car still under warranty? Take it to the dealership and ask them to fix it. Why bother trying to fix anything if the warranty is still valid and you can get it fixed for free.

Comment: @rana - A squeak may not be covered under the warranty. Usually, squeaks and fitment issues are only covered under a much shorter "adjustment" period (12 months). I'm not saying the OP shouldn't take it in and claim it as a warranty repair, just saying they probably won't honor it unless it is physically broken (inoperable). Still though, seeing as how it's a 2015, it still may be covered even by this.

Comment: I was able to cure the squeak.  My amateur guess is the grease wasn't uniformly distributed in whatever the hell is underneath there, so it was getting an uncomfortable dry rub, so I sensually, but firmly worked the tilt up and down repeatedly.